# Linear Programming Confusion about Complexity

Tags: linear-programming

In the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming) page of Linear Programming is told that Linear Programming problems belong to P complexity class.

However, the method generally used to solve Linear Programming problems is the Simplex method that not belong to P. So, does this make Linear Programming problems exponentially complex ?

Comment: the performance of the simplex algorithm may also greatly depend on the specific pivot rule used. simplex method has polynomial smoothed complexity. Please check: [Complexity of the simplex algorithm](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2373/complexity-of-the-simplex-algorithm)

Comment: As example Quick sort has worst complexity of $O(n^2)$ but it's still preferred instead of merge sort with $O(n\log n)$ worst complexity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linear Programming can be solved in polynomial time with [ellipsoid algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsoid_method).

However, in practice, the simplex algorithm is more efficient, despite the fact that its **worst time** run times are exponential.

So in summary : linear programming problems are not "exponentially complex", but they are typically solved with an algorithm that may run in exponential times in worst case scenarios.